# Register button refreshing page and not adding user

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, button

I have an ASPX web page which has four fields, email, confirm email, password, confirm password, and display name. I have put code in the code behind the page so that when the register button is pressed, it should submit the information and add a new user to the database. However, when I click the button, it just refreshes the page. I have tried messing with the code behind so that when the button is clicked it simply redirects to the homepage with no if statements, but it still refreshes the page.
Here's the relevant code behind:

```
namespace PiccyPic
{
    public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void butRegisterDefine(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            butRegister.Click += butRegister_Click;
        }
        void butRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
         using (DataLayer.Repository db = new DataLayer.Repository())
         {
           BO.User user = db.UserGet(txtEmail.Text);

            if (user != null)
            {
                //If the same email exists
                pnlError.Visible = true;
                lblError.Text = "Error: The email you have entered is already assigned to an account.";
            }
            else if (user.Username != null)
            {
                //If the same username exists
                pnlError.Visible = true;
                lblError.Text = "Error: The username you have entered is already assigned to an account.";

            }
            else if (txtEmail.Text != txtEmailConfirm.Text)
            {
                //If the emails don't match
                pnlError.Visible = true;
                lblError.Text = "Error: The emails you have entered do not match";
            }
            else if (txtPassword.Text != txtPasswordConfirm.Text)
            {
                //If the passwords don't match
                pnlError.Visible = true;
                lblError.Text = "Error: The passwords you have entered do not match";
            }
            else
            {
                // Add user
                var newUser = new BO.User(txtEmail.Text, txtPassword.Text, txtUsername.Text);

                db.UserAdd(newUser);
                db.Save();

                Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any javascript. Look for javascript error.

Comment: there are no javascript errors

Comment: This is not Classic ASP. Please retag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your OnClick method set to in your markup? I'm no C# expert, but seems to me that your OnClick is not registered correctly. When does "butRegisterDefine" run?

If you dont have onlick defined, you'll need to run the event registration (butRegisterDefine) somewhere. Page_Load seems a good place. Below snippet works.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Login.aspx.cs" Inherits="ButtonTest.Login" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="butRegister" Text="Register" />
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblSomething"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

CodeBehind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace ButtonTest
{
    public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            butRegisterDefine(sender, e);
        }

        protected void butRegisterDefine(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            butRegister.Click += butRegister_Click;
        }

        protected void butRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblSomething.Text = "Clicked!";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have not defined my onclick in the markup so it's default:




    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="butRegister" Text="Register" />




butRegisterDefine is there because that's how I was taught. You do that void first to define butRegister_Click and then use butRegister_Click in the later functions.